# Match a RegEx to the same Group based on a conditional match of a string pattern- in Golang

Tags: regex, go, regex-greedy

I have two test strings
`mp4/dach/zdf/22/07/220724_traumorte_italiens_romantische_inseln_inf/1/220724_traumorte_italiens_romantische_inseln_inf_508k_p9v15.mp4`

and

`/mp4/none/zdf/21/11/211124_1925_sendung_ban/1/211124_1925_sendung_ban_a3a4_508k_p9v15.mp4`

I want a single RegEx to match the first string to get an output
`/dach/zdf/22/07/220724_traumorte_italiens_romantische_inseln_inf/1/220724_traumorte_italiens_romantische_inseln_inf`

which I get with the RegEx `^.*[mp][4](.+)(?:a[0-9]a[0-9])?(?:.+_.+_.+_|_.+_).*$`
or
`^.*[mp][4](.+)(a[0-9]a[0-9]?(.+_.+_.+_)|(_.+_)).*$`

but this matches the second string as `/none/zdf/21/11/211124_1925_sendung_ban/1/211124_1925_sendung_ban_a3a4`

but my expectation is to match  **3** times **_** if `a3a4` is present; otherwise **2** times **_**
which should get the match `/none/zdf/21/11/211124_1925_sendung_ban/1/211124_1925_sendung_ban` for the second string.

But, somehow this is not grouping (Group -1) as intended.

Any pointers on this is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can capture the whole line that you don't want in group 1, and match what you don't want to keep from the other line, while keeping in group 2 what you do want to keep. Then in the replacement use both groups See https://regex101.com/r/M4XUAF/1 and a [GO demo](https://ideone.com/ZZEr7w)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I want the string to be in group 1 as it is the condition

Comment: In that case you can write it like this: https://regex101.com/r/A0G1hw/1

Comment: Thats matching everything from second string `/mp4/none/zdf/21/11/211124_1925_sendung_ban/1/211124_1925_sendung_ban_a3a4_508k_p9v15.mp4`

but I want only `/mp4/none/zdf/21/11/211124_1925_sendung_ban/1/211124_1925_sendung_ban`

Comment: In your question it states `but my expectation is to match 3 times _ if a3a4 is present; otherwise 2 times _` but there are more than 3 underscores in both example strings. Is there any other logic to it except the number of underscores? Can `a3a4` occur only before or after the last forward slash, or is it always before `508k`? Lookarounds are not supported in Go, do you only want to use a single regex? What do you want to do with the value of group 1, match it or replace it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to match 3 times _ from the end of the string (if a3a4 is present) in reverse direction (starting from mp4); otherwise 2 times _   . Yes, its a condition to set a cachetag that we can use only one regex falling in Group 1

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\S*?\bmp4(/\S*?)(?:_a[0-9]a[0-9])?(?:_[^\s_]*){2}\.mp4$` https://regex101.com/r/fUODg7/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
^\S*?\bmp4(/\S*?)(?:_a[0-9]a[0-9])?(?:_[^\s_]*){2}\.mp4$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\S*?\bmp4` Match optional non whitespace chars, as least as possible, and them match `mp4`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `/\S*?` Match `/` and match optional non whitespace chars, as least as possible
- `)` Close **group 1**
- `(?:_a[0-9]a[0-9])?` Optionally match the pattern in the non capture group
- `(?:_[^\s_]*){2}` Repeat 2 times `_` and any char except `_` and a whitespace char
- `\.mp4` Match `.mp4`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fUODg7/1)